# Convert Single Threaded Server into Multi Threaded in JAVA

Tags: java, sockets, server, client-server

I need to convert this single threaded Server in Multi Threaded one, so i'm able to handle multiple request from a server:

```
public class YASGP {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket server;
        try{
            server = new ServerSocket(5559);

        System.out.println("Listening for connection on port 5559 ....");

        while (true) {
            Socket clientSocket = server.accept();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line = reader.readLine();
            new Thread(new WorkerRunnable(clientSocket)).start();
            while (!line.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("----- " + line);
                if (!line.contains("OPTIONS")) {
                    //  System.out.println("Non c'è nulla!!!");
                } else {
                    timeS = line.substring(line.indexOf("timeS=") + 6, line.indexOf("&url"));
                    url = line.substring(line.indexOf("url=") + 4, line.lastIndexOf("&param"));
                    param = line.substring(line.indexOf("&param=") + 7, line.indexOf("HTTP"));
                }
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
            } 
        }
    }catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not listen on port: 4001");
}
}
private static class RequestHandlingClass {
        public RequestHandlingClass(Socket clientSocket) {
        }
    }
}
```

How i can convert it? Thanks to all

Comment: 1. One thread can be made to handle mutiple client connections. The application will scale better if you don't start a new thread for every client. 2. java and javascript are 2 different languages. Please choose just one.

Comment: Does the current code work at all? It's strange how you spawn a new thread for the clientSocket. What is the purpose?

Comment: i begin to modify the code, yes it work for 1 thread, other one no. Any tip? i'm newbie in coding :)

Comment: @Luke You want tips? If you're new to programming, read tutorials instead of trying to write multi-threaded socket servers. You don't learn driving by jumping into a Formula 1 car either.

Comment: @MinhKieu i need to accept more than one request. Child process (as result of first execution) that can create another child process etc

Comment: @Kayaman unfortunately i need it immediately :(

Comment: @Luke - I understand what the program is doing and it's not correct. I asked the question in hoping you would figured it out. Here are my 2p worth. Server.accept() will be blocked until it received an input. All the code below it should be placed in a new thread to implement the workload. Having the Server.accept() in a while loop will handle more requests so it's fine as it. Let me know if you want me to rewrite that code?

Comment: @MinhKieu I would be glad, if you could do it :)

Comment: Diarmuid already done it :) see answer #2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the 'client processing' code from the server as follows

```
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket server;
        try{
            server = new ServerSocket(5559);
            System.out.println("Listening for connection on port 5559 ....");

            while (true) {
                Socket clientSocket = server.accept();
                new Thread(new WorkerRunnable(clientSocket)).start();
            }

        }catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not listen on port: 4001");
        }
    }
```

then the code that you lifted out goes in to the run method of the workerRunnable class .

Answer (score 1):

I recommend u use the excutorService api.Since it will manager all your threading issue for u behind the scene

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
executor.submit(() -> {
  //Your code here
});
```